# Word search within a sentence and delete previous ones

Tags: php

For example, this sentence:

"`Hello Humanity D. Humanity is a wonderful thing`"

"`Today weather, good D. maybe tomorrow will be bad`"

"`I could not find another sentence D. this last example sentence`"

I have 495 sentences for like this.
Here are the sentence to be deleted

"`Hello Humanity D.` "

"`Today weather, good D.` "

"`I could not find another sentence D.` "

The common feature of each letter is the presence of the letter "`D.`"

How do I remove sentences before `D.`?

```
function removeEverythingBefore($in, $before) {
    $pos = strpos($in, $before);
    return $pos !== FALSE
        ? substr($in, $pos + strlen($before), strlen($in))
        : "";
}
echo(removeEverythingBefore("I could not find another sentence D. this last example sentence", "D. "));
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvTEe.jpg)

Comment: show your expected output and the code you have tried so far

Comment: You are looking for RegEx.

Comment: Tried `preg_replace()`?

Comment: No need for RegEx here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick one line way of doing this:

```
<?php

echo trim(str_replace(' D.', '', strstr($string, ' D.')));
```

An example with output:

```
<?php

$string = 'I could not find another sentence D. this last example sentence';

echo trim(str_replace(' D.', '', strstr($string, ' D.')));
//Outputs: this last example sentence
```

Comment: he wants the entire sentence before D. removed

Comment: that is what the above does

Comment: What if the sentence was "I campaigned for the CND."? That would be removed when it shouldn't. Maybe tweak for a space before the D?

Comment: appreciate it :D

Answer (score 1):

with a [preg_replace](https://regex101.com/r/6fuTyb/1/):

```
$re = '/.*D\.\s*(.*)/';
$str = 'Hello Humanity D. Humanity is a wonderful thing';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

result:
`Humanity is a wonderful thing`

Comment: Why not `explode()`?

Comment: because it may contain several `D.`s

Comment: Where's the problem with that? explode > array_shift > implode

Comment: trim (explode -> array_shift -> implode)  that's just soooo many steps!

Comment: Ironically your code does not even work with 2 "D." http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62be582cb3685dc3cc84d92ffcd3a1b4e350961b

Comment: Thank you @UnamataSanatarai

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of 'D.' with strpos and substract whats after.

$new_sentance = substr($sentance, strpos($sentance, 'D.') + 1);

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: https://regex101.com/r/mvoJDs/1/

```
<?php

$strings = [
'Hello Humanity D. Humanity is a wonderful thing',
'Today weather, good D. maybe tomorrow will be bad',    
'I could not find another sentence D. this last example sentence',    
'I have 495 sentences for like this. Here are the sentence to be deleted',   
'Hello Humanity D. ',   
'Today weather, good D. ',    
'I could not find another sentence D.     '
];

$regex =  '#.+\sD\.\s#';

foreach ($strings as $key => $val) {
    $strings[$key] = preg_replace($regex, '', $val);
}

var_dump($strings);
```

Which will output:

```
array(7) { 
[0]=> string(29) "Humanity is a wonderful thing" 
[1]=> string(26) "maybe tomorrow will be bad" 
[2]=> string(26) "this last example sentence" 
[3]=> string(71) "I have 495 sentences for like this. Here are the sentence to be deleted" 
[4]=> string(0) "" 
[5]=> string(0) "" 
[6]=> string(4) " " 
}
```

See it working here https://3v4l.org/kfPnm

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
$str = 'Hello Humanity D. Humanity is a wonderful thing';
$a = explode("D.",$str);
array_shift($a);
$result = trim(implode("", $a));
```

This way you won't have to fiddle around with regex.
Speed comparison: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a078d7ca01c149aabaaddb335a4b0ad8669fb273